# Concatenate two string in Sybase store procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sap-ase

I am not very familiar with the syntax of Sybase store procedure. I am getting an error with the string concatenation:

```
create procedure calendarList
as
declare @city varchar(20)
declare @aus varchar(20)
declare @combined varchar(200)
declare @result varchar(200)

declare curs cursor for select distinct M_CTN from UnionCal for read only

open curs

fetch curs into @city

while (@@sqlstatus!=2)
begin
    declare curs2 cursor for
    select * from UnionCal where M_CTN=@city for read only  

    open curs2
    fetch curs2 into @aus

    while (@@sqlstatus!=2)
    begin
        @combined = @combined + ";" + @aus
        fetch curs2 into @aus
    end

    fetch curs into @city

    select @city,@aus 
    close curs2

end 

close curs

return
```

The error is in this line:

```
@combined = @combined + ";" + @aus
```

The error message is not very helpful:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1
Server 'DS_LN_D01_X0427', Procedure 'calendarList', Line 24
Incorrect syntax near '@combined'.

Apparently I am not concatenating the string in the right way. Any ideas?

I am using Sybase 12.

Comment: something || otherStuff doesn't work? another point is that @combined isn't initialized...

Comment: @Spaeth nope, it does not work.

Comment: have you tried to initialize it?

Comment: I have reply before your edit, good point, I have had an initialization line @combined='' (these are two single quotes) and I got two error now. I don't understand how sybase handle variables into store procedure.

Comment: errors? still related to concatenation?

Comment: the error message is the same :-( but different line. I think the error is related with the assignment of a value to the variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite simple just add `SELECT` or `SET` before that command:

```
SELECT @combined = @combined + ";" + @aus
```

or

```
SET @combined = @combined + ";" + @aus
```